# When is a locally bounded complex of sheaves globally bounded

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves, derived-functors

Let $X,Y$ be projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ with $Y$ smooth. Suppose $\mathcal{F} \in D(X \times Y)$, the unbounded derived category of coherent sheaves on $X \times Y$. Suppose further that for any closed point $x \in X$ I write $i_{x}:Y \to X \times Y$ for the inclusion along $x$ and that $ \mathcal{F}_{x}=Li_{x}^{*}\mathcal{F} \in D^{b}(Y)$, then I'm pretty sure that $\mathcal{F}$ is not bounded in general. For example pick $\mathbb{Z}$ points in $X$ and label them $x_{i}$ and a point $y \in Y$ then let $\mathcal{F}^{i}=\mathcal{O}_{(x_{i},y)}$.

Suppose however that $\mathcal{F}_{x}$ is bounded independently of $x$. That is $H^i(\mathcal{F}_{x})=0$ for all $i \notin [m,n]$ for some $m,n$ and all $x$. Is it then true that $\mathcal{F}\in D^{b}(X \times Y)$? It is clear when $X$ is also smooth however I cannot make any headway in the general case.

Since $Y$ is smooth we can consider this as a specific case of the more general question: Suppose $W$ is a projective variety with $\mathcal{F} \in D(W)$ such that for all $j_{w}:{w} \to W$ we have $\mathcal{F}_{w}=Lj_{w}^{*}\mathcal{F}$ bounded independently of $w$ then is $\mathcal{F}$ also bounded.

Comment: Do you consider only closed points or all scheme points?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Since you know this when $X$ is smooth, it appears that you can prove this by devissage.  For a proper, birational morphism $\nu:\widetilde{X}\to X$ with $\widetilde{X}$ smooth, since $Li* L\nu^*$ equals $L(\nu\circ i)^*$ for every inclusion $i$ of a closed point of $x$, you conclude that $L\nu^*$ is bounded.  Since the dimension of fibers of $\nu$ is bounded, also $R\nu_*$ maps bounded complexes to bounded complexes.  Thus, $R\nu_* L\nu^* \mathcal{F}$ is bounded.  Now replace $\mathcal{F}$ by the mapping cone of the natural adjunction to $R\nu_*L\nu^*\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you Jason.